# Laravel relationship one to one doesnt work with single page view

Tags: laravel

I have created two models called video and file using Laravel 6.
A video can have only one file.
This is the relationship I created:

**Video**

```
public function file() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\File');
    }
```

**File model**

```
public function video() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Video');
    }
```

If I loop all videos then I get the related media

```
@foreach($videos as $video)
{{$video->link->media}}
@endforeach
```

If I go to the related video single page it doesnt work.

```
{{$video->link->media}
```

Here the route:

```
Route::get('/video/{slug}', 'HomeController@singleVideo')->name('single');
```

I get following error:

```
Trying to get property 'media' of non-object
```

I also add the table Schema:

```
   Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('media')->default('none');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('video_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title',128);
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('url',247);
            $table->string('category',128);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('views')->default(200);
            $table->string('video_youtube_status')->default('off');
            $table->string('video_status')->default('off');
            $table->string('status')->default('off');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Model Video**

```
protected $guarded = [];


public function file() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\File');
}
```

....

Comment: Are the name of the tables standard?
Are you extracting the object including the method with()?

Comment: I recently started programming with laravel...what do you exactly mean.."extracingt the object including the method with?

Comment: Can you update your answer with your controller or the part where you are doing the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), the relation "hasOne" is not applied in this way, the primary model(let's say it's File) will have hasOne like in your code, but the secondary Model will have the Inverse Of The Relationship, which is 'belongsTo' so, in your video Model you should write:

```
public function file() {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\File','file_id');
}
```

This will allows you to access to the entities like:

```
$video->file->some_property
$file->video->another_property
```

and another major problem in your videos table:
this table must have a foreign key to files table, which means:

in your videos migration you should add :

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('file_id')->nullable(false);
  $table->foreign('file_id')->references('id')->on('files');
```

Comment: for this line {{$video->link->media} could you gave more details about it, is not a property inside Video model?
please past the property definition for this property

Comment: I posted the DB tables schema

Comment: please past the whole video model

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)

You should implement the use of `belognsTo` relationship
and your query to get your results set must include the use of method `with()`

```
$users = User::with('podcasts')->get();

foreach ($users->flatMap->podcasts as $podcast) {
    echo $podcast->subscription->created_at;
}
```

Comment: The loop of the videos work when I call the relationship. The problem is in the single video page.

Comment: What you get when you do `$video->toArray();` ?

Comment: I get following: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string